# Unable to emulate mouse buttons with combination keys

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to assign some key combinations to mouse buttons.

I 'm going to use 'vk1Dsc07B' as a virtual prefix key, 
and I'll use 'v' as LButton, 'c' as MButton and 'x' as RButton.

I tried several ways, but I failed. I could click, however, I coudn't drag properly.
Once I tried to drag an object, the pointer grab and release it every 0.1 seconds.
The problem is, I guess, that the key events are sent repeatedly unlike mouse buttons'.

I'm looking for a code which acts as following:

1. keep a mouse button pressed continuously, NOT REPEATEDLY, while I'm pressing combination keys
2. change a mouse button up when I release the one key, other than virtual prefix key, of the combination keys

Here is one of my codes:

```
vk1Dsc07B::Return ; deactivate 'Muhenkan' key in order to use it just as a prefix key
vk1Dsc07B & v::Click,L,D Return
vk1Dsc07B & c::Click,M,D Return
vk1Dsc07B & x::Click,R,D Return
vk1Dsc07B & v Up::Click,L,U Return
vk1Dsc07B & c Up::Click,M,U Return
vk1Dsc07B & x Up::Click,R,U Return
```

another sample:

```
vk1Dsc07B::Return ; deactivate 'Muhenkan' key in order to use it just as a prefix key
vk1Dsc07B & v::Send {Blind}{LButton down}
vk1Dsc07B & c::Send {Blind}{MButton down}
vk1Dsc07B & x::Send {Blind}{RButton down}
vk1Dsc07B & v Up::Send {Blind}{LButton up}
vk1Dsc07B & c Up::Send {Blind}{MButton up}
vk1Dsc07B & x Up::Send {Blind}{RButton up}
```

Maybe most of you don't have 'vk1Dsc07B' key, so please replace it a certain key.

Glad to hear any idea:)

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is *remapping* **two keys** to **one**. AutoHotkey documentation says:

> Although a pair of keys cannot be directly remapped to single key (e.g. it's invalid to write a & c::b), this effect can be achieved by explicitly adding the up and down hotkeys [[link]](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

So, the second solution of yours should actually work:

```
vk1Dsc07B::return    ; you don't need this line. vk1Dsc07B is deactiated by default because of the other hotkeys
vk1Dsc07B & v::Send {Blind}{LButton down}
vk1Dsc07B & v Up::Send {Blind}{LButton up}
; and you need the `{Blind}` keyword here, do you??
```

, but it doesn't. This only works with 'normal' keys like `send {a down}`. The problem is that when you hold down `vk1Dsc07B & v`, `{LButton down}` will be sent repeatedly. This leads to "the pointer grab and release it every 0.1 seconds".
So, we'll have to look for another way, trying to have `{LButton down}` be sent only once, when the hotkey is triggered.

I came up with the following solution which stores the hotkey trigger in a variable:

```
Ltriggered := false
Mtriggered := false
Rtriggered := false

vk1Dsc07B  & v::
if(!Ltriggered) {
    Send {LButton down}
    Ltriggered := true
}
return
vk1Dsc07B  & v Up::
Send {LButton up}
Ltriggered := false
return

vk1Dsc07B  & c::
if(!Mtriggered) {
    Send {MButton down}
    Mtriggered := true
}
return
vk1Dsc07B  & c Up::
Send {MButton up}
Mtriggered := false
return

vk1Dsc07B  & x::
if(!Rtriggered) {
    Send {RButton down}
    Rtriggered := true
}
return
vk1Dsc07B  & x Up::
Send {RButton up}
Rtriggered := false
return
```

Comment: Many thanks! It works fine.

_> you don't need this line. vk1Dsc07B is deactiated by default because of the other hotkeys_
I misunderstood it:) I'll learn more!

Sincerely,